# How Heroku is turning my http express server into the https server?

Tags: node.js, express, http, heroku, https

### **Problem**

I made an express server with `app.listen` as following:

`` app.listen(config.PORT, _ => { console.log(`Server started at port # ${config.PORT}`)}) ``

I deployed it on Heroku.

Now it is working with **https**. Check out: https://dnt-ecommerce.herokuapp.com/

I checked the requests in the browser devtools and it was still **https**

### **Question**

How come my http express server is serving https requests by the frontend?

**GitHub Rep**
https://github.com/siddiqian/dntstores-ecommerce

Answer (score 1):

https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1815

As it says.... https works on .heroku.com even when we configure a custom domain. So its a default feature (thanks to heroku). HTTPS will stop working on .herokuapp.com when we Configure SSL on a Custom Domain and manually upload your own certificate.

Comment: But my basic question is that in server's code, I have not explicitly stated the https server as you can see from the code line of the app.listen(... which I included in my answer. Heroku does convert it into https, but how? If in code I have not added it's support. How?

Comment: https is not something that you configure on the application level - its SSL that acts on the transport layer. I would recommend you to go through the network TCP/IP layer model of internet. The baseline is that you wont be configuring https on your code.

Comment: Plus like the answer says - its something heroku does for you.